# Voltaic pile: question on components

Tags: voltage, batteries, electromagnetism, battery-chemistry

I have some questions on voltaic pile components.

The following show images of the voltaic pile.  The vertical pile in I1 has four outside (labeled m in Fig 2) bars and one bar in the center perpendicular to the base. The center bar is also shown in drawing I2 with a sine wave departing the top.  I3 shows the same with a conductor leaving the same center terminal.

Do these bars serve a purpose other then supporting the pile? Do they have electric current?

I suspect the bars are only supports based on the other images with them removed.

There is a bucket in Fig 2. I’m assuming this is where the electrons flow.

Is this true and if not, what is the bucket’s purpose?

Finally Figure 3 and 4 are connected together via label c. It looks like batteries in series, similar to Figure 1.

Do the two buckets signify electrons moving from one bucket, through the battery and to the second?

I1:
[image: a]

I2:
[image: b]

I3:
[image]

Comment: the images seems the one in Volta letters (I'm Italian, we study that stuff) the four corner bars are only mechanical, that I can tell you. As for the buckets they are simply the 'open' version of the stack. Details here https://knowledge.electrochem.org/encycl/art-v01-volta.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meters were invented two decades later (Oerstead's compass.)

So, how did Volta discover that something was going on here?   Wet fingers!   With hands well soaked in water (or seawater, or vinegar,) touching a ~10V battery produces a detectable shock-feeling.

In figure one, the "measurement instrument" is Volta himself, dipping one finger from each hand into the two final teacups.   (Find Volta's first paper, see if he was using salt water, vinegar, weak lye, etc.)

A public demonstration common at the time was to use your fingers to compress the stack, since the stack had poor conductivity otherwise.   And, the harder you pushed, the worse the electrical-pain!

So, in figure two, you'd put one hand in the teacup (bucket,) then use wet fingers to push downwards on the top of the stack, until the shock-feel became apparent.   No frogs' legs needed   ...especially if you had any tiny cuts on your fingers.  Zat givz a zing!

The four posts in figure 2 are wood insulators (or glass, for Zamboni or DuLuc dry-piles,) and were used to clamp the pile down under pressure, using an end-disk not shown.   With a clamped disk, the output wouldn't be changing all the time, no longer depending on hand-strength.

Figure three can zap the experimenter in the same way as figure one, but only using two teacups, without the experimenter touching the stack.   (THe two stacks need to be clamped down.  Or, have a third party pushing down on the heavy shorting-bar.)

Figure four should be WAY more that twice as painful, when you stick your fingers in those two teacups.   Yeesh.

[image: 1801 Bulletin des Sciences #3]
above from "Bulletin des Sciences #3, 1801" see [ISIS V89, No2, p310 (6/1998)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/237757)

Those flower-thingies appear to be part of a pile-compressing fixture, with an inverted cylindrical cup on top of the stack.   This could possibly serve as an early on/off switch, since the max output current is nearly zero when the electrolyte sponge-layers aren't being compressed.

> Do the two buckets signify electrons

Note that electrons are mostly a metals thing.

Electrons never flow in salt water, or in human bodies, or in acids/bases, or in the dirt, or when leaking across contaminated insulators or through ionized air.  Metals (wires) involve electrons.  Battery electrolytes don't, and neither do human bodies.

In chem class, and in engineering school, we learn that electricity is NOT electrons like we were taught in grade school.  (That was a lie-to-children, a "for dummies" concept aimed at youngsters who can understand flows of physical particles, but not abstract concepts such as "Electric Current.")

Inside salt water, positives and negatives both flow (in opposite directions, both at the same time!)   In acids, protons are flowing, in alkaline, it's OH- ions as charge-carriers.   Inside humans, electric currents are flows of Na+, K+, Mg+ H+, OH-, Cl-, and a few other ions.   No electrons at all.   (And those H+ positive ions have another name: protons.)

Science-misconceptions taught in grade-school:  atoms look just like tiny solar systems.  Above Earth's atmosphere there's zero gravity.  Ben Franklin's kite was struck by a lightning-bolt.  Electrons zoom through wires at lightspeed.  Airfoils work because the top surface is longer.  ELECTRIC CURRENT IS A FLOW OF ELECTRONS!   (all these are wrong, of course!)

Comment: Electric current is the flow of charges particles. I should have been clear that these are charges particles moving through the electrolyte.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, the bars only serve to contain the precarious pile of discs.  If they were current-carrying then each disc would be shorted to each other and you'd get a whole lot of nothing and maybe some hydrogen gas.  The buckets are likely part of some other demonstration, electrolysis maybe.  Other drawings of voltaic piles show wires or primitive screw terminals attached to the ends.

Comment: My guess is that the buckets are full of electrolyte solution, to keep the spacers between the metal discs damp.

Comment: Meters were invented years later.  To detect the pile-voltage, you must connect your body to the terminals, via skin soaked in salt water, then feel the pain/shock/muscle-clench.   So, the buckets most likely were there as "skin electrodes" for attaching to the measurement "instrument" (the experimenter's own fingers/arms/chest!)

Comment: @SimonB how would the electrolyte be drawn up?

Comment: @Nick capillary action through a wick

Answer (score 0):

Holding the structure of heavy metal disks was done possibly by wooden poles.

The A stood for Ag = Silver, and Z for Zn = Zinc. He focused only on this galvanic electro-potential of bimetals and completely ignored the massive electrochemical energy of an insulated acid or alkaline cell.  I guess coal wasn't clean enough or ceramic plates with metallic compounds like used in 2V cells or lead plates didn't exist (?)

it took Volta decades to be successful with his pile battery and I'm sure he had hydrogen explosions at times. (4% H2 and 0.0001% O2 is sufficient to detonate with a spark.)

After all, batteries are just high-density versions of super big caps or "ultracaps" with a minimum metallic electro potential voltage at a low state of charge with a double-layer effect.

A tiny 18650 Li-Ion cell is 10,000 Farads compared to a massive 100F superlarge Ultracap. But the low corrosive effects the Ultracap has on conductive activated-carbon electrodes and insulation, make it good for 1k more cycles than a Li-Ion.

All the energy is stored above Vmin in the electrolyte of the capacitive acidic or alkaline dielectric-metallic interface.

By the time he was awarded his due prize in London, wars and Eu country power struggles diverted his legacy of research to other countries.

He did use saltwater for a wet electrode-interface material but then the corrosion was a problem, so clean water was mostly used. It took Daniell to make a useful primary acid cell with Zinc-sulphate in sulphuric acid.  The plate material was too thin to be rechargeable.

I wonder if this could be a symbol of "flower power" ;)
[image]

The cell bilayers and buckets were just a series accumulation of voltage and series resistance, so the power was pretty puny.

It would take another century before [Nernst](https://knowledge.electrochem.org/encycl/art-n02-nernst.htm) would properly explain how a battery works and then someone else (?) a couple decades later to theorize the overpotential theory.

Amps * Ohms = Nernsts . ha ;)

Volta was first so he gets the credit.  Similar to Marconi's invention was done by Graham Bell earlier in PEI and Boston and credit changed hands.

I don't think I've ever seen Volta make a *fish battery* even though the Torpedo fish was always his role model for a battery. (like an e-eel)

Comment: I think the flower is the Fleur De Lis. If you look at the lower left it looks like the head of a snake with the tail over the flower. Perhaps an indication of current or electron flow

Comment: It also looks like his sketches show some sort of enclosure around the battery, but not sure